# Vue.draggable - swapping between two list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuedraggable

I have a problem. I need to organaze two draggable table like swapping.

**1 table:** have 7 fixed items.

**2 table:** Other items.

When you swapping items from the second table to the first, a dialog box should appear to confirm swapping.

I did swap for first list, but not understand how to do for two table.

my code now:

```
    <template>
  <table>
    <draggable v-model="items" tag="tbody" :move="handleMove" @end="handleDragEnd" :options="{animation:500}">
      <tr v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
        <td>{{ item.id }}</td><td>{{ item.name }}</td><td>{{ item.age }}</td>
      </tr>
    </draggable>
  </table>
</template>
<script>
import draggable from "vuedraggable";

export default {
  components: {
    draggable,
  },
  data() {
    const items = [
      { id: 1, name: "Bianka Effertz", age: 37 },
      { id: 2, name: "Mckayla Bogan", age: 20 },
      { id: 3, name: "Estevan Mann", age: 17 },
      { id: 4, name: "Cloyd Ziemann", age: 55 }
    ]
    return { items }
  },
  computed: {
    orders() {
      return this.items.map(x => x.id)
    }
  },

  methods: {
    handleDragEnd() {
      this.$toast.show('dragEnd')

      this.futureItem = this.items[this.futureIndex]
      this.movingItem = this.items[this.movingIndex]
      const _items = Object.assign([], this.items)
      _items[this.futureIndex] = this.movingItem
      _items[this.movingIndex] = this.futureItem

      this.items = _items
    },
    handleMove(e) {
      const { index, futureIndex } = e.draggedContext
      this.movingIndex = index
      this.futureIndex = futureIndex
      return false // disable sort
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please show your current code?

Comment: You can use @end event listener on the dragabble with a handler for your dialog `@end="confirmHander`